# Cargar mensaje en un div

Tags: botón, div

El click en un botón dispara una función síncrona que insume unos segundos. Durante este tiempo se produce el congelamiento de la página para mostrar que ningún control/componente responde hasta tanto termine dicha función.

```
const funcionCostosa = ( costo ) => {
 let total = 0;
 for(let i=0; i<costo*1_000_000; i++){
    total += i;
 }  
}

const mensaje = ( texto ) => {
    document.querySelector("#mensajes").innerHTML = texto;
}

btnCostoso.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ 
  mensaje('bloqueado...');     // <- PORQUÉ NO SE MUESTRA ???
  console.log('bloqueado...'); // ok
  funcionCostosa(5000);  // bloqueo intencional de varios segundos
  mensaje('desbloqueado');     // ok
  console.log('desbloqueado'); // ok
} )
```

Por consola todo bien, muestra los textos previo y posterior a la funcionCostosa(), pero:

¿ Porqué no se muestra el mensaje() inicial: 'bloqueado...' ?

Comment: ¿Qué tal, Rubén? Sería de ayuda conocer el código de la función `mensaje()`. Por otro lado, para ejecutar una serie de instrucciones luego de un determinado tiempo, puedes utilizar el método [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta???? Por que pasa esto? cual es la solución al código?? como se debería ejecutar un proceso pesado??

Comment: Falta info, en general lo ideal es que compartas al menos el mínimo código verificable para poder entender tu problema, hacer las pruebas pertinentes y darte una respuesta en el menor tiempo posible. Te sugiero leer [ask] para evitar que tu pregunta pueda ser ignorada o incluso eliminada. Espero tus cambios, bienvenido a la comunidad!

Comment: Hola Luis, gracias por tu atención. Voy a editar la consulta

Comment: JS tiene un sistema de tiempo de ejecución llamado [Evento Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop), donde el llamado a repintar la pantalla lo pone JS y no hay forma que lo pongas tu. Al presionar el botón el repintado de la pantalla lo hace al último, es por eso que los mensajes de la consola se ven correctamente, pero la actualización de `mensaje` no aparece hasta el final, es decir ese `innerHTML` se ejecuta, pero no existe el repintado de la pantalla

Comment: La solución fácil es obligar a que exista un ciclo entre medio, por ejemplo en este código `btnCostoso.addEventListener("click", async ()=> mensaje('bloqueado...');   await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));  funcionCostosa(5000);  mensaje('desbloqueado'); } ) `. Pero la mejor solución es usar `Service Worker` para procesos pesados